# WPF ComboBox in grid - how to specify search path in viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagridtemplatecolumn

We have a DataGridTemplateColumn that uses a ComboBox in the DataTemplate:

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Things">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox
                          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                          TextSearch.TextPath="Name"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Things}">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" Margin="0,0,12,0" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

We need to let the user specify the search path for the ComboBox.

```
 TextSearch.TextPath="{Binding SearchPath}"
```

How do I specify that this binding refers to the top-level viewmodel, not the current item from the Things collection (which Name and Index refer to)?

Thanks for any insights --

Comment: If you want to find the SearchPath property of the DataGrid's DataContext/viewmodel (I think that's the top-level viewmodel you mean), `TextSearch.TextPath="{Binding DataContext.SearchPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"`. You could also give the DataGrid (or whatever XAML element has the desired viewmodel for a DataContext) an `x:Name` attribute and use `ElementName` in the binding.

Comment: @edplunkett Perfect, thank you.